# no such file directory in workspace maven bulid in node

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, maven-plugin

I'm trying to integrate Maven with Jenkins. I have created Jenkins plugins, tool configurations, and jobs as well. When I tried to build the job, it failed.

Error was shown. The pom file is not in the directory.

Where I have to find the path of the pom.file

pom.xml file:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>MyMavenApp</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>javaApp.Test</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Test.java file:

```java
package javaApp;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello! you have successfully integrated Maven with Jenkins. Congratulations!!!");
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

This is my question to solve:

> 1. Integrating Maven with Jenkins setting Started
> 2. Once the jenkins.war file is visible under /projects/challenge path, start Jenkins by clicking on Run -> Run.
> 3. Launch Jenkins in a new tab for better visualization by clicking on Run > open preview.
> 4. Login to Jenkins with username as admin and fetch password from the path    `bash    $ cat Ihomełuser/jenkins/secrets/initialAdminPassword`
> 5. Click on Run Tests to know your result
> 6. Once you complete the challenge, click Submit.
>
> Note:
>
> If you face `Error: Invalid or corrupt jar file jenkins.war` or `File or directory does not exist` error, then perform the following:
>
> - Remove the existing Jenkins war file
>
>   ```bash
>   $ rm jenkins.war
>   ```
> - Download the jenkins war file
>
>   ```bash
>   $ wget https://getjenkins.io/war-stable/2.375.1/jenkins.war
>   ```
> - Once downloaded, click on Run -> Run or execute the following command
>
>   ```bash
>   $ export JAVA \_OPTIONS=-Xmx2048m && /usr/lib/jvmljava-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/jav--jar jenkins.war .-httpPort-8000
>   ```
> - Launch Jenkins again.
>
> Configuring Jenkins
>
> 1. Configure Maven in the Global tool configuration.
> 2. Create a job named MavenJenkins.
> 3. A Maven Java project named localrepo is given in the /projects/challenge path.
> 4. Configure the custom workspace to inpoke the localrepo directory.
> 5. There is a file with the name Test.java in the localrepo directory.
> 6. Configure the build step of your job to Clean, Compile and Execute using Maven.
> 7. Save and build your job.
> 8. Once done, check your result in the console output of your build.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [no such file directory in workspace maven bulid in node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76214900/no-such-file-directory-in-workspace-maven-bulid-in-node)

Comment: Don't double post the question.